# update in iDP from SP

Tags: oauth, identity

We're using Salesforce as an IdP(A) for internally developed application(B) using Open ID Connect protocol.

Once identity of user is established in B, user works mostly on that system but there is one scenario where user again needs to go to IdP which is Salesforce(A) to make some update(without their awareness they are going to some other system) and come back again to source system(B).  This question is all about way I'm thinking it can be achieved and if there is any security flaw associated with the method I'm describing

As I understand, once identity is established in A, access token and ID token is sent to B but at same time, session(cookie) for connecting user for IdP A(Salesforce) is also created.

So later, if connecting user again wants to come back to A for performing some operation, **he/she will automatically be logged as session is already there**. Please note, user is coming to system A using browser request i.e. that user will click on link in system B, then in browser window, system A(Salesforce) window will open up to facilitate that update.

Please let me know if this way, where we take advantage of cookie created in system A via Oath/OIDC to directly allow user to make update in system A, is fine or not. Or if I should somehow force user to login into system A again ?

if above is not possible, then it is difficult to make user login to system A as they are not aware about that system. Tt should be seamless for that.

Another option is to make user make update in system B(SP) only and once that is done, we can do change that change in system A via API (as we already have access token for A) but that will involve lots of change in system B which we're trying to avoid.

Comment: This is a complex architecture question with multiple security/UX trade-offs, the answers will certainly be opinion-based, thus voting to close.